# Starting with discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I just started working on a discord bot but i am getting an issue i cant resolve, my code is:

```py
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('Nzk1MDEzNDE4ODQyNzE4Mjc4.X_DL8Q.TUgZIM5FUg49RuBCmZWCfUvt8pE')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

and im getting the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Ollie Williams\OneDrive\Coding\python\Odd's Adventure Series\Discord Bot\RealPython Discord Bot\Start 1.py", line 16, in <module>
    client.run(TOKEN)
  File "C:\Users\Ollie Williams\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 708, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Ollie Williams\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 687, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ollie Williams\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 650, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\Ollie Williams\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 499, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

i think something has not properly installed but im not sure what

Comment: Did you really create an environment variable with the name `Nzk1MDEzNDE4ODQyNzE4Mjc4.X_DL8Q.TUgZIM5FUg49RuBCmZWCfUvt8pE`?

Comment: The error is in the system library, as shown by the traceback.

Comment: how do i fix the discord library?

Comment: It's not the library's fault. I am 99% sure that you do not have an environment variable with such a nonsensical name. And therefore your `TOKEN` variable has a `None` value

Comment: the token is the Discord bots token

Comment: What token?  You are trying to fetch an environment variable with `os.getenv` - and you did not define such an environment variable

Comment: Oh, thanks that worked, not sure what i did but it works

Comment: And now that you've published your bot token, please revoke it and use a new one.

Comment: Don't worry i already did when i realised what i did

Answer (score 0):

instead of having the token in an environment variable try to hard code it into the script simply like this:

```py
import os
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = "<The actual token string>"

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

or write it into a file:

```py
import os
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
with open("<filename>", "rt") as f:
    TOKEN = f.read()

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

client.run(TOKEN)
```